# Vim: How to open new vertical split for file under cursor

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, neovim

I know `gf` opens the file under cursor, and `CTRL-w` `f` opens the file under cursor in a new split window.

I'm probably being greedy but, how do you open it in a new **vertical** window?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From normal mode, you could type `C-w f C-w L` or `C-w v gf`, and from the command-line you could execute `:wincmd f | wincmd L` or `:vert wincmd f`.

They are not strictly equivalent, though.

With `C-w f C-w L` and `:wincmd f | wincmd L`, the height of your vertical viewport will be maximized no matter the current layout. So, for example, if you have a horizontal viewport below, its width should be decreased:

```
        +-----------------+     +--------+-------+
        |  path/to/fileC  |     |        |       |
        |                 |  →  |        |       |
        |      fileA      |     |  fileA | fileC |
        +-----------------+     +--------+       |
        |                 |     |        |       |
        |      fileB      |     |  fileB |       |
        +-----------------+     +--------+-------+
```

With `C-w v gf` and `:vert wincmd f`, the height of your vertical viewport should be the same as the current one, and thus it shouldn't affect the horizontal viewport below:

```
        +-----------------+     +--------+-------+
        |  path/to/fileC  |     |        |       |
        |                 |  →  |        |       |
        |      fileA      |     |  fileA | fileC |
        +-----------------+     +--------+-------+
        |                 |     |                |
        |      fileB      |     |      fileB     |
        +-----------------+     +----------------+
```